# [UIBarButtonItem convertPoint:toView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, uibarbuttonitem, unrecognized-selector

I link my UIBarButtonItem to a View Controller in XIB using modal segue,
once I click the UIBarButtonItem the error below came out and I can't find what is the reason for it, anyone please help me. Thanks.

```
2014-09-12 11:08:26.551 testingApp[28195:60b] -[UIBarButtonItem convertPoint:toView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd22a270
2014-09-12 11:08:26.688 testingApp[28195:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIBarButtonItem convertPoint:toView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd22a270'
```

Comment: `UIBarButtonItem` isn't a `UIView`. Post the actual code causing this error.

Comment: @rmaddy oh now I know why already, post this as the answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `convertPoint:toView:` method is from the `UIView` class. `UIBarButtonItem` does not extend `UIView` (directly or indirectly).